# Not able to fetch defect details from Agile Central (previously known as Rally)

Tags: java, rally

Below is the code which i have used to fetch the defect details from rally. But i am getting exception at getresponse line. Not sure if it is authentication issue or issue with the get request. Can any one help me with the code to get the defect details from rally.

```
serverz="https://rally1.rallydev.com"
```

`RallyRestApi apiKeyApi = new RallyRestApi(serverz, "apiKey");`

`Assert.assertTrue(apiKeyApi.getClient() instanceof ApiKeyClient);`

`GetRequest request = new GetRequest("/defect/1234");`

`GetResponse getResponse = api.get(request);`

eg: https://rally1.rallydev.com/#/75804949228d/detail/defect/1234 - this defect details i want to fetch

Comment: That all looks fine.  Can you add some details of the exception you're getting?

Comment: I have added a proxy url and was able to get the details. But when I try to create a defect I am getting 401 error. Can you please help.

Comment: You're sure your api key is valid?  Does your proxy require authentication?  Again, if you can post your actual error/stack trace it will help a bunch...

Comment: also be sure your api key has full access and is not "read only"